# Seg Fault while using numpy with Python3

Tags: c, numpy, python-3.2

I was trying to use the Python C api with numpy and Python3 and it is throwing a seg fault inside import_array(). I tried to debug it using gdb and it showed a seg fault for PyModule_GetDef() . This is my code

```
#include<Python.h>
#include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>
static PyObject* testBasic(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    printf("Successful \n");
    return PyLong_FromLong(1);
}
static PyObject* testMmult(PyObject* self, PyObject *args) {
    PyArrayObject* obj;
    //  if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!",&PyArray_Type, &obj)){
    //      return NULL;
    //  }
    /*  if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"i",&a)){
        return NULL;
        }
    */
    //  Py_INCREF(obj);
    //PyArray_Return(obj);
    return PyLong_FromLong(1);
}

static PyMethodDef testPythonMethods[] =
{
   {"testBasic",testBasic,METH_VARARGS,"testing whether everything compiles."},
   {"testMmult",testMmult,METH_VARARGS,"testing mmult"},
   {NULL,NULL,0,NULL}
};
static struct PyModuleDef testPythonModule = {
   PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
   "testPythonModule",
   NULL,
   -1,
   testPythonMethods,
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
  PyInit_testPython(void){
    (void)PyModule_Create(&testPythonModule);
    import_array();
}
```

Anyone else faced this kind of problem before ?

Comment: Your initialization function should return the module you create before, i.e. `PyObject *m = PyModule(..); import_array(); return m;`. Other than that, the code runs just fine here, no segfaults..

Comment: Yup, it works on mine too. Thanks a lot.